# SetWebViewClient error

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

When I use

`webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());`

in Android, there is an error:

> The method setWebViewClient(WebViewClient) in the type WebView is not
>   applicable for the arguments (WebViewSampleActivity)

It says "change setWebViewClient to setWebChromeClient" but when I do that, it says "change setWebChromeClient to setWebViewClient". Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

To use:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

HelloWebViewClient must be a subclass of WebViewClient:

```
public class HelloWebViewClient extend WebViewClient {
```

Currently your HelloWebViewClient is extending WebViewSampleActivity, if this class is named properly, it is an Activity subclass and not a WebViewClient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (example code)

```
public class SinaActivity extends Activity {
private WebView myWebView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new SinaActivityClient());

} }
```